# How to read innerHTML of element while using electron in node,js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, electron

I want to read the innerHTML from elements on a webpage I loaded into my electron window with `win.loadURL("https://www.sample.com");`. How can I get the innerHTML of an element with the ID "name" or the class ".name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I think you want to execute some javascript on the content and return the value of the inner html. Here is an example from a test project I created to investigate for you.

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load',()=>{
let code = `var promise = Promise.resolve(document.getElementById('name').innerHTML);
            promise.then(data => data)`;
mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(code, true)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result) // will be your innherhtml
  })
});
```

Here is [electrons documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture) on the matter.
Here is an [example github](https://github.com/fk1018/electron-quick-start) I created pulling the inner html from an element using this method.

Comment: just realized i am targeting by id using getElementById('name'). if you want to target by class use. getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHtml to get the inner html of the first element with the name class